# React Redux setState after action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my EditStudent component in React where I am using Redux for state management. This is my code of the component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getStudentDetail} from '../actions/studentActions';

class EditStudents extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            name:this.props.student.name,
            email:this.props.student.email,
            address:this.props.student.address
        }
        // this.state

    }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div>
      <form>
              <p>
                 <label>Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="name" 
                 value={this.state.name} 
                 onChange={this.onInputChange}
                />
              </p>
              <p>
                 <label>Email</label>
                 <input type="text" name="email" 
                 value={this.state.email} 
                 onChange={this.onInputChange}
                 />
              </p>
              <p>
                 <label>Address</label>
                 <input type="text" name="address"
                  value={this.state.address} 
                  onChange={this.onInputChange}
                  />
              </p>
            <button type="submit">Update</button>
          </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
  onInputChange(e){
      var name = e.target.name;
    this.setState({[name]:e.target.value});

  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getStudentDetail(this.props.studentId());
  }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=>{
    return {
        getStudentDetail: (id)=>{
            dispatch(getStudentDetail(id));
        },
        studentId: ()=>{
            return ownProps.match.params.id;
        }

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
    return {
        student:state.students.student
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(EditStudents);
```

Here I am having the problem displaying ajax response in text input field. I am setting component in the constructor but when ajax request completes state is not set.

Is it possible to set state after ajax completes?

Comment: Where is your reducer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it by adding componentWillReceiveProps() function on component.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        name:nextProps.student.name,
        email:nextProps.student.email,
        address:nextProps.student.address
    })
  }
```

Thanks so much, **Sakhi Mansoor** for the help.

Comment: you should checkout `getderivedstatefromprops` also. `componentWillReceiveProps` is going to be deprecated in latest version of react

Answer (score 1):

you need to store input value in your state as you're re-rendering your input so changes are not getting reflected.

Do the folowing changes:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        email:this.props.student.email,
        address: this.props.student.address
    }
}
```

In you render:

```
<p>
   <label>Email</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onInputChange('name)}/>
</p>
<p>
   <label>Address</label>
   <input type="text" name="address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.onInputChange('name')}/>
</p>


onInputChange= name => event => {
        this.setState({
          [name]: event.target.value,
         });
   };
```

Comment: In my case this.props.student comes from ajax request.

Comment: So you need to do this in componentDidMount()

Comment: where are calling your API request ?

Comment: I am calling it on my localhost api. My api response is 

`{"user":{"id":"2","name":"suresh","address":"adhikarki","email":"suresh@gmail.com"}}`

Comment: In which component you're calling it ? please share the code? ?and what errors you're getting

Comment: Monsoor I have updated the codes as your suggestion. Can you check and suggest me, please. Thanks for your help

Comment: You will get props in componentWillReceiveProps() when you redux state gets updated.

Comment: Thank you so much Sakhi componentWillReceiveProps fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

First -

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.userProfile();     // Redux Action
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
    this.setState({
      firstName: nextProps.user.firstName
    });
  }
```

Second -

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.userProfile();   // Redux Action
    this.state = {
      firstName: ""
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {firstName: this.props.user.firstName };
  }
```